# Access geojson key-value pairs that are not geometry or properties?

Tags: javascript, json, properties, geojson

```
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -77.155585,
                            40.056708,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -77.150315,
                            40.04536,
                            0
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "id": 42001030101,
            "Households": 1000,
            "Income": 74597
        },
```

I am using the google maps JS API. I cannot use the `getProperty` function because the data doesn't have the properties grouped together.

How can I access each of these pieces of data?

Here is what I tried before I realized that you can't use the properties function.

```
        map.data.setStyle(
          function(feature){
            let income = feature.getProperty('Income');
            let color = 'blue';
            if (income > 10000){
              color = 'red'
            }
            return {
              fillColor: color,
              //strokeColor: "green",
              strokeWeight: 0.3,
            };
          }
        );
```

Comment: Check here: https://geojsonlint.com/ - you will see it's not valid geojson for 3 reasons.

Comment: Does that make it inaccessible? The data can be mapped just fine, I just need to be able to grab those few values at the bottom. If that's not possible, how could I programmatically put those values into a properties section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [geojson spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.2):

> A Feature object has a member with the name "properties".  The value
> of the properties member is an object (any JSON object or a JSON null
> value).

As your feature doesn't have a `properties` member, you can 'repair' it so that any member that is neither `type` nor `geometry` is bundled as a member of `properties`.

This should enable your existing code using `feature.getProperty()`.

```js
const data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-77.155585, 40.056708, 0],
            [-77.150315, 40.04536, 0]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": 42001030101,
      "Households": 1000,
      "Income": 74597
    }
  ]
}

const repairGeoJsonProps = (fc) => {
  return {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": fc.features.map(ftr => {
      const props = Object.entries(ftr).filter(k => ["type", "geometry"].indexOf(k[0]) < 0);
      return {
        "type": ftr.type,
        "geometry": ftr.geometry,
        "properties": Object.fromEntries(props)
      }
    })
  }
}

console.log(repairGeoJsonProps(data));
```